# How I can delete the item from list view

Tags: android, image, android-listview, textinput

I have a listview and a button in my layout file.
I'm adding items to listview on click of that button.
I need a way that make my item in the list disappear when I click the item.

Answer (score 0):

set up an onitemclicklistener on you list view, remove the item when it is onclick and then refresh the list

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    /* remove the item at position */
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```